# Distances in geodesic triangles in manifolds with negative curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, geodesic

I have a question about the proof of the this statement (page 42 in "Non-positive curvature: geometric and analytic aspect", J. Jost):

**Lemma:** Let $M$ be a complete, simply connected Riemannian manifold with sectional curvature $K\leq - k <0$. Let $p\in M$ and let $c_1, c_2:[0,1]\rightarrow M$ be geodesics starting at $p$ and let $c:[0,1]\rightarrow M$ be the geodesic from $c_1(1)$ to $c_2(1)$. Then there exists a constant $C(k)>0$ depending on the curvature such that for every $t\in[0,1]$ there exist $s\in[0,1]$ and $i\in\{ 1,2\}$ with $d(c(t), c_i(s)) \leq C(k)$.

They claim this is a consequence of the following result, which I managed to prove with Rauch Comparison Theorem:

**Claim:** Consider $M$ as in the Lemma take $p\in M$ and $c:[0,1]\rightarrow M$ a geodesic which does not contain $p$. Let $f(s)=d^2(p, c(s))$, then $f''(s)\geq 2\sqrt{k}d(p, c(s))\coth(\sqrt{k}d(p, c(s))\Vert c' \Vert^2$

How does the Lemma follow from the claim?

My attempt is the following: take $c_1, c_2, c$ as in the Lemma. Consider $q$ the footpoint of the perpendicular from $p$ to $c$ so that $d(p, c([0,1]))=d(p,q)$. Fix $t\in [0,1]$, then I think it is possible to find a point $s\in[0,1]$ such that $d(c(t), c_1(s))=d(q,p)\leq d(c(t), p)=: g(t)$. Now we consider a function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0)=L(c_1)^2, f(1)=L(c_2)^2$ and 
$f''(t) = 2\sqrt{k}g(t)\coth(\sqrt{k}g(t))\Vert c' \Vert^2$. 
This should imply that $d(p, c(t)) \leq f(t)$. But then, how can I further estimate $f(t)$ with respect to the curvature?

Comment: Are you sure you copied correctly? There is no such a thing as "**the** geodesic from $c_1(1)$ to $c_2(1)$." Since $M$ is compact and of negative curvature, there will be infinitely many such geodesics and some will violate the "thin triangle" property stated in your post. I suspect, the assumption is that $M$ is complete and simply connected.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan, oh yes, you are right. I edited the text.

Comment: You should make one more correction: ... $t\in[0,1]$ there exist $s\in[0,1]$ and $i\in \{1,2\}$ such that $d(c(t), c_i(s)) \leq C(k)$. To be honest, I do not see how Lemma follows from the Claim. The way I would prove Lemma is: (1) First in dimension 2 by using Gauss-Bonnet formula, (2) in general, filling in the given geodesic triangle by a solid 2d triangle of curvature $\le -k$, using a ruled surface or a minimal surface.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan, also adjusted. I will give it a try with your suggestion, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Moishe Kohan, can you give a hint of how to get this claim in dim 2 with Gauss-Bonnet? It seems I can't really figure it out

Comment: Suppose you have a 2D triangle $T=\Delta xyz$ with geodesic boundary and curvature $\le -k<0$. GB formula gives you an upper bound on its area (in terms of $k$). Now, if you have a point $p$  on the side $xy$ of $T$ which is distance $\ge r$ from the two other sides of $T$, consider the geodesic half-disk $D\subset T$ centered at $p$ and of radius $r$. Its area is $\ge \pi r^2/2$. This, together with the upper area bound on $T$, gives you an upper bound on $r$.

Comment: Thus, you get $r\le C(k)= \sqrt{2/k}$.

Comment: An alternative argument is to compare the function $f$ on your manifold to the function $f_k$ on the surface of the hyperbolic plane of constant curvature $-k$. I assume you proved Claim by verifying that for $f_k$ the equality holds. If this is indeed the case, I can describe an alternative proof.

Comment: Yeah, to prove Claim I compared $f$ and $f_k$ and proved that for $f_k$ equality holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition. Let $X$ be a complete simply connected Riemannian manifold of sectional curvature $\le -k<0$, let $X_{-k}$ be the hyperbolic plane of the (constant)  curvature $-k$. Given a geodesic triangle $\Delta xyz$ in $X$, its *comparison* triangle in $X_{-k}$ is a geodesic triangle $\Delta \bar{x} \bar{y} \bar{z}$ whose respective side-lengths equal those of $\Delta xyz$. Given a point $p$ on the geodesic $yz$ in $X$, its comparison point $\bar{p}\in  \bar{y} \bar{z}$ is the unique point such that 
$$
d_{X}(y,p)=d_{X_{-k}}(\bar{y}, \bar{p}). 
$$

The claim that you proved implies that  every geodesic triangle $\Delta xyz$ in $X$ and its comparison triangle 
$\Delta \bar{x} \bar{y} \bar{z}$ in $X_{-k}$ satisfy the *comparison inequality*:
$$
d_X(x,p)\le d_{X_{-k}}(\bar{x}, \bar{p}).
$$
The reason is that the inequality on the 2nd derivatives implies that the distance function $d_X(x,p(t))$ decreases faster than $d_{X_{-k}}(\bar{x}, \bar{p}(t))$ (until it reaches the point of global minimum), where $t=d_X(x, p(t))$ is the arc-length parameter for the geodesic $xy$.

Subdividing the triangle $\Delta xyz$ along the segment $xp$ and applying the comparison inequality again yields the 2nd comparison inequality:
$$
d_X(p,q)\le d_{X_{-k}}(\bar{p}, \bar{q}),
$$
for all $q\in xy, p\in yz$ and their comparison points $\bar{q}\in \bar{x}\bar{y}$, $\bar{p}\in  \bar{y} \bar{z}$.

Now, what's left is to prove

Lemma 1. Suppose that $\Delta \bar{x} \bar{y} \bar{z}$ is a geodesic triangle in $X_{-k}$. Then every point $\bar{p}\in \bar{y} \bar{z}$ on the side  $\bar{y} \bar{z}$ of the triangle belongs to the $C(k)$-neighborhood of the union of the two other sides of the triangle.

One can either use hyperbolic trigonometry or direct calculation in a hyperbolic plane model or the Gauss-Bonnet formula to get such an inequality. For instance $C(k)=\sqrt{2/k}$ will work.

Combined with the second comparison inequality, it yields

Lemma 2. Suppose that $\Delta x y z$ is a geodesic triangle in $X$. Then every point $p\in y z$ belongs to the $C(k)$-neighborhood of the union of the two other sides  of the triangle.